# Is there anyway to further improve my bad question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365433/what-do-the-characters-used-regexp-command-mean received a few downvotes, for reasons I mostly understand. I didn't read the guidelines clearly enough, and asked for resources and recommendations, but I've now taken the steps to edit those out.

I'd like to seek help improving the question so that it may be useful in the future, help on asking good questions in the future. I'd also like to stop the sinking hole of endless downvotes it seems to be going into (it's averaging one an hour).

What I have done already after reading the guidelines:

1. I have removed any references to asking for outside help on
   understanding
2. I have removed all noise and unnecessary words or sentences
3. Tried to remove words to make it sound more professional

If it is so extremely horrendous, maybe it should be removed?

Comment: I've locked it while it's being discussed here.

Comment: You *really* couldn't find any documentation on what the various special characters are in RegEx?  You sure?

Comment: I did find documentation on regex but I was still confused as to what the characters did. The working code was from an answer on another question, and I had trouble understanding how it worked while reading it. I wanted to ask for a plain words interpretation so I could try to implement a method for my own code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried to close it, but I had received an answer that was upvoted very quickly after I had posted it. So I could not delete it myself.

Comment: I have seen other questions asking for "plain wording", "baby language", "Easy For My Understanding" (examples from memory). But SO is "for professional and enthusiast programmers" (the [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) and so, if you find you *literally* need a step-by-step explanation of concepts well explained in other sources, you may be too far off-topic.

Comment: @Servy I should have tried harder before asking on stack, i get it. If you're a mod, then just close the question since it's of little value to future users, as I asked in the post. I can't do it myself.

Comment: @DanceDreamer Mods are the ones with the little diamonds next to their names. Like Robert Harvey on the first comment here. Just fyi.

Comment: @Jongware Asking to have a *specific* concept explained isn't wrong at all, so long as you actually do research before asking the question and make a good faith attempt to find the answer yourself before asking.  The thing to be explained also needs to be reasonably scoped.

Comment: To answer the question in your title, it *may* be salvageable and even helpful for others if you break it down and try to explain what you understand of it, as much as you can. Then explain in a little more detail what you still don't understand of it.

Comment: @Jongware yes, you're probably right. Before reading through meta today I didn't realize SO was like that. I first joined and posted a few questions over 4 years ago and only returned this month to ask about TCL/SAML. I'll stop, just remove the question for goodness sake.

Comment: @RobertHarvey please delete my question.

Comment: @DanceDreamer Relax. Take a deep breath, and remember it's only fake internet points. If you haven't read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet, you might want to have a look. At the bottom are links to other helpful resources about how to ask better questions. If you're starting to feel frustrated, I suggest walking away for a bit to take time to cool down. Trust me, it really does help. :)

Comment: @Kendra I'm frustrated because I believe I'm making an effort to fix a bad question I have made one time, but most of the responses I'm getting are just telling me what I already know, that it's a bad question. I wouldn't be posting here if I didn't want to try and improve question asking skills.

Comment: @DanceDreamer I understand that- What I'm saying is that if you take a few minutes or an hour or so to try to get unfrustrated, you won't have to worry about saying something you don't really mean and getting worse responses. Plus, in the time that you're cooling off, someone could come and offer a better solution.

Comment: What codeMagic put in [their last comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269106/is-there-anyway-to-further-improve-my-bad-question#comment80973_269106) might be very helpful- Explain what you already knew about the regex before you posted the question and clarify what you didn't know. Break it down a little bit. And since it's just the regex you're trying to understand (that's what I'm understanding from your SO question) you don't really need the rest of the code block in this context, I believe.

Comment: @Kendra also frustrating that now someone is going into my posts from 4 years ago to down vote them. Really mature folks.

Comment: From the looks of it, at earlier you got an upvote on that question which gives you a net gain of rep, and you don't know why someone did that. It could be someone found it looking for their own solution and didn't find it helpful, and earlier someone else _did_ find it helpful. Try not to take downvotes personally- They are not meant to judge you but the quality and helpfulness of your posts. And I wouldn't start getting angry about it- That's a sure way to attract negative attention on Meta. Just a word of advice.

Comment: Why should you care? You got the answer, let it GTH now. Just ask better questions from now on :)

Comment: The question was ... well ... not very good. But that you had understood. For what it worth, as of myself, I think you deserve some encouragements for coming here in he hope of improving your _future_ SO experience. It would have been much more easy for you to go away with your answer and come back in few weeks/month with an other bad question. So don't take personally what we can say here. Our (including _you_) goal is to improve SO. I really hope you will stick with your positive attitude!

Comment: "Can anyone interpret this code that has special characters with regexp command?" seems ambiguous and for some reason (at least to me) almost feels offensive... I would rewrite it to something more along the lines of "Could someone please explain what is being done in this code snippet with regards to the regexp?  I am trying to do something similar and am having difficulties understanding the approach being taken here."... Admittedly, that's still probably somewhat open to interpretation but I think it is less ambiguous and a bit truer to the actual question you wanted to ask

Comment: @DanceDreamer "mature"? What are you talking about? Age of a post is irrelevant (btw. I never did understand the stupid policy against "digging up old threads" on ordinary forums) - its content is relevant. I also reviewed all of your posts, my edits (hopefully correct) should give you some additional insight on how to properly format questions. I did downvote some of your questions, but also upvoted some of them - the net result is positive.

Answer (score 15):

Your question only received the downvotes for not showing your research effort and it's quite localized, and not as helpful to future readers.

Also, [it's answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3622940).

[Asking questions is hard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593): **make it count** and post well-put content that other readers will likely benefit from your question, or at least learn what's being conveyed. You can try to simplify the problem in your question down to:

> "What do the regular expression constructs `{`, `^`, `([^=]*)`, `(.*)` and `$` mean?"

And try to expand / comment on your code.

And to be honest, for short questions like these, you'd have better luck asking them in [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex).

Comment: I like this answer, and would like to suggest adding the words `regular expression` before `constructs` in the suggested title.

Comment: @jmstoker Good point! It will improve the visibility of the question as well.

Comment: This is the [second meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269135/how-can-i-improve-my-question) about regex within a few hours. SO is already being used like a regex writing service by some users, chat users may not be be very willing to write regexes either.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I understand your concerns, but at this rate [we have too many regex questions flowing into the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), while posting it in chat rooms is equally annoying, short questions (and unhelpful ones) are likely to get downvoted a lot, and if they do belong somewhere, [you would still have better luck asking them in chat rooms](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bqA31.png).

Answer (score 10):

> I'd like to seek help improving the question so that it maybe useful in the future, **help me ask good questions in the future**, and stop the sinking hole of endless down votes it seems to going into (it's averaging one an hour).

I won't insist on "read how to ask" or the various advices you might have received within various comments. But there is one key point I'd like to mention. By participating on SO, the community expects you **act like a busy professional talking to another busy professional**.

For me, that is having a decent technical background, being responsible, not wasting our time and trying to make your participation profitable for both of us.

Sounds harsh? Maybe, but it isn't really. For example, "being responsible" is not much more than seriously doing some research yourself or being able to properly format your question. "Don't waste our time" is providing the required information, and not much noise around or writing in a clear and understandable way. "Trying to make your participation profitable" might be narrowing down your issue enough so it can be useful beyond your specific case. Those are only some example, but I hope you see my point.

Comment: That's some good advice for OP to follow, but how can he improve this specific question?

Comment: @Unihedron The flaws with the question are pretty inherent to the question.  He didn't bother to take the time to try to solve it himself.  Any changes that would make the question one that couldn't be answered with a simple google search would be radically changing the entire question.  Not all questions are salvageable; he simply need to learn from the mistake and not continue to make it in the future.  Spending a whole bunch of time trying to improve a question that, even after that effort, still won't be a good question, isn't productive.